# IOS Xcode Subview does not cover all of the screen in real device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am new to Xcode and IOS programming and am creating an app using Swift . I have ran into a peculiar issue when I run my app on the emulator the dimensions look good (height and width) however on the real device they are too short in both length and width.**What I want is to get my subview to cover the screen completely on my I-phone device like it does on the emulator**.The subview is the orange background UIColor that you see below it starts right underneath the UISearchBar and it is supposed to cover the whole area below it .You can see the difference below: the 2nd image is the emulator notice how the subview width is the same as the UISearchBar and the 3rd and last image is of my real device and see how the SubView width is not as wide as the searchBar . Any suggestions would be great . Also as I stated before the Orange background is a View under the main View and it is called **Registration_View** . I want to make it as long and wide as the Original view but start it under the SearchBar which I already have working. Any suggestions would be great. This is what I have in my code and I have auto-layout on

```
  @IBOutlet weak var Registration_View: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Registration_View.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    }
```

[image: How it looks on the emulator]

How it looks on the emulator which is great
 [image: How it looks on the emulator]
     How it looks on my device width and length are short
[image: How it looks on my device]

Comment: What have you done with the autolayout constraints?

Comment: Based on the resolution of the images, it seems that you are using a simulator of a 4.7 inch device and your actual device is 5.5 inch. Therefore my guess is that you constrained the view with fixed width (equal to 4.7 inch screen). You should use flexible width with fixed margins (equal to 0) to superview instead.

Comment: Xcode usually displays a separate constraint node in the view hierarchy, which I'm not seeing. Turning auto layout "on" isn't enough. You need to actually add some constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use autolayout and set view constraints to have 0 margin from superview leading and trailing and bottom.